# IE JS сбор значений SELECT'ов

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

IE не понимает атрибут value в select'е и вот думаю каким образом заменить... вот фрагмент кода

```
function send_form() {
    var x = document.getElementById("SEIF_content");
    var data = {
        "SEIF": {}
    };
    data["cat1"] = document.getElementById("cat1").value;
    data["cat2"] = document.getElementById("cat2").value;

    for (var i = 0; i < x.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (x.childNodes[i].nodeType == 1 && x.childNodes[i].type == "select-one" && * * x.childNodes[i].value * * ) {
            data["SEIF"][x.childNodes[i].name] = * * x.childNodes[i].value * * ;
        }
    }

    // ajax отправка данных
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Советую использовать не чистый JS а jquery
Там уже профиксено много проблем кросбраузерности
и писать проще

```
$("select#my_select").val();
```

Да и вообще форма отправляеться по ajax в одну стрку

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

Comment: вот хотелось бы без jquery))))

Comment: Вас напрягают лишние 32кб кода?

Answer (score 0):

на событии **onclick**, т.е. собираем все option'ы в массив, на onclick инициализируем какуето переменную, соответственно value вы "генерируете сам" и потом с нее читаем, с подобной проблемой не сталкивался, но должно помочь...